# Sass to CSS and viceversa

Tags: css, sass

In Sass documentation about merging selectors on page

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders

following sass code

```
#admin .tabbar a{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#demo .overview .fakelink{
    @extend a;
}
```

should compile to

```
#admin .tabbar a,
#admin .tabbar .overview .fakelink,
#admin .overview .tabbar .fakelink {
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

so why this compiledcode not producing same output when converting CSS to sass
using converter like http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It produces correct code.  It is difficult to extract extend from css because there is no way to know if the original sass had an extend function, or just a simple heirarchy.   Since both produce the same results, but different levels of complexity, the simplest way to convert css to sass is to just go with heirarchy

Comment: When there are multiple ways to produce any given piece of CSS, why would you expect it to choose one or the other?